# Must the image of $f(x)$ be a half ellipse?

Tags: analysis, arc-length

Consider the smooth function $f$ on interval $[0,1]$ with the constraint that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. My question is that, if the arc-length of $f$ is fixed, and assume that the area of the figure enclosed by the $f$ and $x$-axis is the largest within all the admissible function (that is all the smooth function $g$ satisfying that $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and the length of curve $(x,g(x))$, $x\in (0,1)$ equals to $l$), must $f$ be a half ellipse?

Intuitively, I guess this conjecture is valid combining some physical intuition, but I can't know how to prove it.

Indeed, I can "translate" this question into the following:

Define two functionals on space $F=\{f\in C^\infty([0,1]):f(0)=f(1)=0\}$:
$$
L(f)=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx,\\
E(f)=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
$$

Denote
$$
\lambda=\sup_{f\in F, L(f)=l} E(f),
$$
where $l$ is a fixed positive constant. Suppose $f\in F$, $L(f)=l$ and $E(f)=\lambda$, does $f$ satisfies
$$
\frac{(x-1/2)^2}{a^2}+\frac{f(x)^2}{b^2}=1
$$
for some constants $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$? Notice that this question doesn't possess a variational structure, so I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: 1) $\frac{(x\color{red}{-1/2})^2}{a^2}+\frac{f(x)^2}{b^2}=1$ 2) Besides, what is your definition of "smooth" ? $C^n$ for some $n$,  $C^{\infty}$ ? If it is $C^n$, I have some doubts that a condition on the length of a curve is enough to give a unique solution. 3) Have you attempted to test with function $g(x)=ax(1-x)$ with a convenient $a$ (in order to warrant that the curve has the good length...)

Comment: Thanks, I've made edits. The smooth means $C^\infty$, as described in the question. Actually I haven't tried this function. I believe this question can be solved by a variational method, but I don't know what goes wrong when I try to formulate a variational structure. I'll try to test with the function you gave. Thanks!

Comment: The max area curve is a part of a circle. In that sense it is an ellipse, though since it's actually a segment of a  circle that seems an odd way to describe it. It's one case of the isoperimetric inequality. I recall it being called Dido's problem.

Comment: My intuition says that it will be a circular arc rather than (half) an ellipse. Maybe your intuition is influenced by the [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) shape that hanging chains make in the presence of gravity. Note that if your length $l$ is more than $\pi$, the circular arc will no longer be a function.

Comment: I meant $\pi/4$ of course.